# Finding palindrome number in java

Tags: java, palindrome

```
import java.util.*;
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input a prefer number :");
        int num=input.nextInt();
        int reverse=0;
        while(num!=0){
            int num1=num%10;
            reverse=(reverse*10)+num1;
            num/=10;
        }

        System.out.println("Reverse num is "+reverse);
        if(num==reverse){
            System.out.println("The number is palindrome");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to confirm whether it is a palindrome number or not when I input a number by the keyboard.But I couldn't get it.In the 7th line of my code,I've initialized variable "reverse" as 0.So when I make a condition in 14th line,"reverse" acts as 0.That is what should be,but i want to make "reverse" equal to the value which gets in line 10.What should I do ?

Comment: Your issue is that you're destroying the `num` variable as you build the `reverse`. When you compare at the end, `num` will be 0 which will not be equal to `reverse`.

Comment: Well if you want to be really cheap, just do: ```boolean isPalindrome = new StringBuilder(num + "").reverse().toString().equals(num + "");``` thou I admit, this is probably not the best solution

Answer (score 2):

Assign num to another variable as its get changed

```
import java.util.*;
class Example{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input a prefer number :");
    int num=input.nextInt();
    int number  = num ; // assign to anaother variable as num gets changed 
    int reverse=0;
    while(num!=0){
        int num1=num%10;
        reverse=(reverse*10)+num1;
        num/=10;
    }

    System.out.println("Reverse num is "+reverse);
    if(number==reverse){
        System.out.println("The number is palindrome");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Try again");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind helps

Comment: To OP, I recommend using some names that _mean_ something though, using names `num1`, `number`, and `num` at the same time just makes it confusing to read.  It'll help your understanding of the situation in my opinion as well.

Comment: Much easier if you read the number as a character string instead of an int.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider treating the number as a string.

1. It allows arbitrarily large numbers.
2. You can then use StringBuilder to reverse the string.

```
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Input a preferred number :");
            String str = input.nextLine();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
            String reverse = sb.reverse().toString();
            System.out.println("Reverse num is "+reverse);
            if(str.equals(reverse)){
                System.out.println("The number is palindrome");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Try again");
            }
        }
```